# DevExpress theme showing white text on inputs ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application in which I want to apply a certain theme.
However, the theme has some problems. It shows white text on inputs. And I tried to solve that with the theme builder by putting all text color to black  but the problem was not resolved :(
Actually the problem consists only when I use DevExpress controls not ASP.NET ones.
Here's an example:
[image]
Please Help.

Comment: Make sure you use the `!important` keyword if you want to override the default white color. In your case, `color: black !important`. Was that the problem?

Comment: @BishopBarber I added a CSS rule ` input { color: black !important; } ` but it didn't work

Comment: Could you post the CSS code of your override (with the selector and everything)? I suspect your problem lies there.

Comment: @BishopBarber http://pastebin.com/QiCRExXm